# Draw 2 parallel lines

Tags: graphics, drawing, vector-graphics

How can I calculate the points to draw 2 parallel lines.

I know the start and end points for the centre of the parallel lines.  To makes thing a little bit harder, it needs to support straight and Bezier curved lines.

Comment: For any given line, There's an infinity of lines parallel to it. Which one do you want to draw ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague, but here's a possibility. Hope that helps.

For a segment (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) you can calculate another segment, n pixels away in a direction represented by angle a this way

```
x1b = x1 + n cos a
y1b = y1 - n sin a
x2b = x2 + n cos a
y2b = y2 - n sin a
```

Comment: In this case, what is the angle a? Should it be 90? if they're parallel lines?

Comment: I noticed when I followed your approach my lines are parallel but not of the same height as the main line. There is an offset, I want my parallel lines to be level.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the same height. Can you describe your problem ?